# How can I execute SQL file which contains several other SQL files using gradle?

Tags: groovy

How can I execute SQL file which contains several other SQL files using gradle?

I tried using following code:

```
gradle.class.classLoader.addURL(new File('SQL/ojdbc6.jar').toURI().toURL())       
def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(JDBCURL, DB_PROP_SCHEMA, DB_PROP_PASSWORD,       'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')

String sqlFilePath = "testsql.sql"
String sqlString = new File(sqlFilePath).text

sql.execute(sqlString)       
sql.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL file which contains several other SQL files" ... ?

Comment: SQL file is executing other sql files.